# Does it make sense to use the present for something that happened 10 years ago?

Tags: present-tense, tense-agreement

Does it make sense to use the present for something that happened 10 years ago?

> "Britain makes the most advanced airplane. (It was made 10 years ago)"

In what situation would it make sense?

Comment: When quoting something? By the way, where did you encounter this sentence, would you please provide more detail?

Comment: There's a common rhetorical technique called the [historical present](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_present) where, once the time period has been established, the present tense is used to narrate events in that time period.  This both makes the storytelling more compelling (by making it sound contemporary) and avoids more complicated tenses when describing events that are in the past or future relative to the narrative frame.